# Send email through SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have contact page on my website and I want users to enter Their name and email id (no password) and send email on button click.

I did Google and all solutions i am getting requires user password,

```
public static void SendMessage(string subject, string messageBody, string toAddress, string ccAddress, string fromAddress)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    // Set the sender's address
    message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

    // Allow multiple "To" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
    if (toAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string addr in toAddress.Split(';'))
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
        }
    }
    // Allow multiple "Cc" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
    if (ccAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string addr in ccAddress.Split(';'))
        {
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
        }
    }
    // Set the subject and message body text
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = messageBody;      

    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtpHost";
        smtp.Port =portno;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fromEmail", "fromPassword");
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }

    // Send the e-mail message
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

But I don't want to force users to enter password. Is there any other solution using SMTP?

The error I am getting is `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: You appear to be accidentally writing a phishing program.  You should not be asking users for their passwords.  Most likely you need to obtain the password for your SMTP server, since anonymous sending is usually locked down.  This would be a password *you* control, not your user.

Comment: Yeah...That is logical... And I tried that too, but I get error as "Failure sending email". I am sure username and password are correct

Comment: The InnerException property will help you solving this.

Comment: Can u please share the InnerException you get?

Comment: The Inner exception i get is "failure to connect to remote server"... I guess there is some problem in rights or may be some firewall issue.. How can i check connection with my smtp host? Is there any way other than telnet?

Answer (score 0):

I have this function in my utility class , and it works like a charm.

```
public static bool SendMail(string Email, string MailSubject, string MailBody)
    {
        bool isSent = false, isMailVIASSL = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerUseSsl"]);

        string mailHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerAddress"].ToString(),
        senderAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSenderUserName"].ToString(),
        senderPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerSenderPassword"].ToString();

        int serverPort = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServerPort"]);

        MailMessage msgEmail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(senderAddress), new MailAddress(Email));
        using (msgEmail)
        {
            msgEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msgEmail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            msgEmail.Subject = MailSubject;
            msgEmail.Body = MailBody;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailHost))
            {
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.EnableSsl = isMailVIASSL;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderAddress, senderPassword);
                smtp.Port = serverPort;
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(msgEmail);
                    isSent = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return isSent;
    }

<!-- Mail Server Settings -->
<add key="MailServerAddress" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="MailServerPort" value="25" />
<add key="MailServerSenderUserName" value="username@gmail.com" />
<add key="MailServerSenderPassword" value="password" />
<add key="MailServerUseSsl" value="True" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Ali Umair, but your code requires "sendersAddress" and "SendersPassword", which i dont want

Comment: these are the username and password for you r account which will semd email usually noreply@yourdomain.com. These aren't user's email and password whereas the email in parameters is the user's email address.

Comment: Well make a gmail's email address to send emails and use fallowing appsettings. Updated the code with appsettings section of config file


I checked it again and its working fine on my gmail's email address.